# How do I make a (mock) bank system?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am rather confused. I have searched for an hour for an explanation for this.

Here's the deal. I would like to make a (mock)bank login system. I want a username and password login box, and I want to have it when you click a button that says Login, it takes the user to a specific webpage. For the moment, I don't care how long or complex it is, I only want to use HTML, CSS and Javascript. I only know those languages for the moment. It seems really simple, but I cannot find it ANYWHERE on the internet, and I am confused. If anybody could help me, it would be nice.

Comment: Hello Simon, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Whilst we are happy to answer coding related questions, please be aware that questions like these (with no code) are likely to be deleted ultimately. If you have some code you have tried, please edit your question and include it here. We may be able to help you on where you've got a problem then.

Comment: And on another note, be aware that client-only authentication only works against people who don't know any JavaScript. For serverside authentication, there are two ways it can go: the first, htaccess authentication (assuming Apache server) requires no coding ([this site](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/) can get you started quickly); the other is to code your own serverside solution, which you will probably be unable to do without learning another language (since your hosting most likely won't support JavaScript solutions like node.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few elements you need to be aware of when writing a simple form in HTML;

**The `<form>` Tag**

This is where you describe what you want the form to do and where to send it.

I won't go through all the options here, but when you want the user to submit details you usually use the `post` method. We do this with the code `method='post'`.

You then need to say where you're sending the form, which is usually another webpage with some sort of scripting capability, such as PHP, ASP.net, or similar. We do this with the code `action='process.php'` where process.php is the page that the form is being sent to. Use of a server side language is more likely to be a acceptable solution to process the form.

We can put these two parts, called arguments, inside the `<form>` tag like this;

```
<form method='post' action='process.php'>
```

**`<input>` Elements**

For the purposes of this form, we'll concentrate on the text input elements.

In the simplest form, input elements just require a `name` and a `type`. The name is an identifier so we know what information was entered in what field when processing the form. The type could be `text`, `password`, `email`, `date`, and a few others. We're going to use the first two here, so the code will look like.

```
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
```

The `<br>` signifies we want the next bit of content on a new line.

**Submit Button**

Don't forget your button to submit. The code for that is;

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Couldn't be simpler (you can change the text on the button by changing the `value`).

**The Finished Product**

Let's put that all together;

```
<form method='post' action='process.php'>
   Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
   Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Don't forget to end your form with the closing `</form>` tag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "I only want to use HTML, CSS and Javascript" - what will process the form?

Comment: @Amadan I'm going to assume you didn't read this bit. "another webpage with some sort of scripting capability, such as PHP, ASP.net, or similar [...] use of a server side language is more likely to be a acceptable solution to process the form."

Comment: I know what the OP said. Both the comment from yourself and my explanation in the answer should be enough.

Comment: I did read it. And OP specifically said he doesn't want to use it, the point you did not address. The answer, while perfectly correct, is thus useless unless you can add a PHP file for him, or point him to a third-party service equivalent.